# why do we have offer(E e) and offerLast(E e) methods in Deque, even though they solve the same purpose

Tags: java, collections, java-6, deque

I am trying to understand, why do we need `Offer` and `OfferLast` methods in `Deque`, as both these methods add the elements at the end/tail of the `Deque`. What is the significance of it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Queue interface was added in Java 5. It defined the [`offer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#offer(E)) method, which adds an element at the end.

(The `offer` method and the [`add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add(E)) method both return booleans. They differ in that `add` is permitted to reject the element and return false only if the element is already present in the collection. The `offer` method can reject the element for other reasons, such as the queue being full.)

With `Queue.offer`, there is little question about the semantics, as elements are generally added to the tail of a queue and removed from the head.

The [Deque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) interface was added in Java 6. A deque allows elements to be added to and removed from *both* the head and tail, so `Deque` defines `offerFirst` and `offerLast` methods. A deque is also a queue, so `Deque` is a sub-interface of `Queue`. Thus it inherits the `offer` method from `Queue`. That's how `Deque` ends up with both `offer` and `offerLast`.

We probably could have gotten by without adding `offerLast`, but that would have left asymmetries in the `Deque` interface. Many operations work on both the head and the tail (add, get, offer, peek, poll, remove) so it makes sense for all of them to have -first and -last variants, even though this adds redundancy. This redundancy occurs with other `Queue` methods as well, such as `add` and `addLast`, `peek` and `peekFirst`, `poll` and `pollFirst`, and `remove` and `removeFirst`.

Answer (score 2):

In a Deque (Double-Ended Queue), you have two methods: Offer and OfferLast, which both add elements at the end (tail) of the Deque. The distinction between them may not be immediately obvious, but it can be meaningful in certain situations.

Here's the simple difference:

**Offer:** This method adds an element to the end (tail) of the Deque, but it doesn't specify the exact position within the Deque. It just says, "Add this element to the end."

**OfferLast:** This method explicitly adds an element to the very end (tail) of the Deque. It specifies that the element should go to the absolute end of the Deque.

The significance of this difference is that in some Deque implementations, especially those that offer various insertion points (e.g., both the head and the tail), using OfferLast can ensure that the element is placed at the very end, without ambiguity.

However, in many common Deque implementations, Offer and OfferLast might behave the same way because they both add elements to the tail. The distinction becomes more important when you're working with more specialized Deque structures where you might have multiple insertion points or specific constraints on where elements can be added.

So, in simple terms, Offer and OfferLast are there to give you flexibility in adding elements to a Deque, and the difference matters more in specific scenarios where you want to be explicit about where the element goes. For many standard use cases, you can use either method interchangeably.

Answer (score 0):

So you can use the same object both as a queue and a deque.

Comment: But as Deque is extending Queue, why cant we make use of the same method which is available in Queue?

Comment: Moreover, offer method is calling OfferLast in turn. public boolean offer(E e) {
        return offerLast(e);
    }

Comment: It's an interface design issue, nothing more. The designer preferred having offerFirst() and offerLast() for clarity reasons instead of having offerFirst() and offer().

Comment: but my question is , there is a method called Offerlast() and Offer(). Why do we need both?

Comment: You don't NEED them both, but the designer of the Deque class found it better to add an offerLast() method so programmers could write easier to read code.